# Logstash Grok filter reading wrong value

Tags: exception, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, grok

I am currently trying to setup some data collections for our app using the full elk stack (Beats - Logstash - ElasticSearch-Kibana). So far everything is working as it should but I have a requirement to capture statistics on the exceptions thrown by the applications (e.g. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)

I am not really interested in the stack trace itself so I went ahead and added a separate grok filter just for the exception.

**Example of Message:**

```
2016-11-15 05:19:28,801 ERROR [App-Initialisation-Thread] appengine.java:520 Failed to initialize external authenticator myapp Support Access || appuser@vm23-13:/mnt/data/install/assembly app-1.4.12@cad85b224cce11eb5defa126030f21fa867b0dad
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not check if provided root is a directory
    at com.myapp.io.AbstractRootPrefixedFileSystem.checkAndGetRoot(AbstractRootPrefixedFileSystem.java:67)
    at com.myapp.io.AbstractRootPrefixedFileSystem.<init>(AbstractRootPrefixedFileSystem.java:30)
    at com.myapp.io.s3.S3FileSystem.<init>(S3FileSystem.java:32)
    at com.myapp.io.s3.S3FileSystemDriver.loadFileSystem(S3FileSystemDriver.java:60)
    at com.myapp.io.FileSystems.getFileSystem(FileSystems.java:55)
    at com.myapp.authentication.ldap.S3LdapConfigProvider.initializeCloudFS(S3LdapConfigProvider.java:77)
    at com.myapp.authentication.ldap.S3LdapConfigProvider.loadS3Config(S3LdapConfigProvider.java:51)
    at com.myapp.authentication.ldap.S3LdapConfigProvider.getLdapConfig(S3LdapConfigProvider.java:42)
    at com.myapp.authentication.ldap.DelegatingLdapConfigProvider.getLdapConfig(DelegatingLdapConfigProvider.java:45)
    at com.myapp.authentication.ldap.LdapExternalAuthenticatorFactory.create(LdapExternalAuthenticatorFactory.java:28)
    at com.myapp.authentication.ldap.LdapExternalAuthenticatorFactory.create(LdapExternalAuthenticatorFactory.java:10)
    at com.myapp.frob.appengine.getExternalAuthenticators(appengine.java:516)
    at com.myapp.frob.appengine.startUp(appengine.java:871)
    at com.myapp.frob.appengine.startUp(appengine.java:754)
    at com.myapp.jsp.KewServeInitContextListener$1.run(QServerInitContextListener.java:104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: fh-ldap-config/
    at com.upplication.s3fs.util.S3Utils.getS3ObjectSummary(S3Utils.java:55)
    at com.upplication.s3fs.util.S3Utils.getS3FileAttributes(S3Utils.java:64)
    at com.upplication.s3fs.S3FileSystemProvider.readAttributes(S3FileSystemProvider.java:463)
    at com.myapp.io.AbstractRootPrefixedFileSystem.checkAndGetRoot(AbstractRootPrefixedFileSystem.java:61)
```

**Example of grok statement:**

```
grok {
patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
match => ["message", "%{GREEDYDATA}\n%{JAVAFILE:exception}"]
}
```

**Testing on the grok debugger shows correct results:**

```
{
  "GREEDYDATA": [
    [
      "2016-11-15 05:19:28,801 ERROR [App-Initialisation-Thread] appengine.java:520 Failed to initialize external authenticator myapp Support Access || appuser@vm23-13:/mnt/data/install/assembly app-1.4.12@cad85b224cce11eb5defa126030f21fa867b0dad"
    ]
  ],
  "exception": [
    [
      "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"
    ]
  ]
}
```

**Problem**

When I add the configuration to logstash it captures the Caused string instead of the exception name, even though the "Caused" string is after another new line character. However it works perfectly for other exception messages such as :

```
016-11-15 06:17:49,691 WARN  [SCReplicationWorkerThread-2] ClientJob.java:207 50345 Error communicating to server `199.181.131.249':`80'. Waiting `10' seconds before retrying... If you see this message rarely, the sc will have recovered gracefully. || appuser@vm55-12:/mnt/deployment/install/app app-3.1.23@cad85b224cce11eb5defa126030f21fa867b0dad
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:223)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readBoolean(DataInputStream.java:242)
    at com.myapp.replication.client.ClientJob.passCheckRevision(ClientJob.java:279)
    at com.myapp.replication.client.ClientJob.execute(ClientJob.java:167)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:534)
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you setting the mutiline in the input or filebeat input , 
like this to show the pattern start with ISO8601
I think maybe you mutiline not fetch the whole line

```
input {
         beats {
            port => 5044
            codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[\.,][0-9]{3,7} "
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
            }
           }
        }
```

Comment: Multiline is currently set and working. When I inspect the full message value I can see the entire message including the New Line characters.

Comment: The GREEDYDATA i think will catch all the line even in the \n char ,so i suggest you choose another regular to split it

Comment: GREEDYDATA ignores \t and \n , i think I figured it out, I need to change the regex to ignore anything starting by "Caused by"